# Confluent CLI not giving any response for produce

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I am trying to consume and produce the messages of Kafka's confluent cloud.
Here the consume command gives the response but when I am trying to produce it, it's not giving any response and getting stuck. can someone please help me here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The produce command is waiting for **you** to type something until you press `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+D`, as stated.

The only response it'll give is if there is a connection error since the producer send requests are asynchronous.